# How to fix Gradlew:Properties not debugging

Tags: dart, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradlew

Running "flutter packages get" in first_flutter_app...              7.2s
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO Camon CX in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\IB\Desktop\Android\myapp\berry_networks\Dart test\Flutter App\first_flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\IB\Desktop\Android\myapp\berry_networks\Dart test\Flutter App\first_flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
  >   Illegal char <<> at index 9: C:/users//.android\analytics.settings
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
  Command: C:\Users\IB\Desktop\Android\myapp\berry_networks\Dart test\Flutter App\first_flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: There seems to be a problem in your android gradle file, you should post it here maybe we can spot the issue.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mosxf.png this is the image @danypata

Comment: @Olaitan we need the *text* (not an image) of your `analytics.settings`